# How to apply filters on rows in aspose cells for java

Tags: java, aspose-cells

My excel file would have two columns - Type and value.After data has been inserted using smart markers, I want to add all the values belonging to the same type . How can this be done? Auto filter require range which I don't know as my excel file is populated with values dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

For applying auto-filters, I think you do not actually need to specify the full range (with specific number of rows), you would only require to mention the columns (e.g "A1:B1") on which you are going to apply filters. So, once your data is populated based on Smart Markers, you will make auto-filters on and even add your custom filter (for your specific type) accordingly, see the sample code segment below:
e.g
Sample code:

```
............

    Worksheet worksheet = worksheet.getWorksheets().get(0);
    AutoFilter autoFilter = worksheet.getAutoFilter();
    autoFilter.setRange("A1:B1");
    autoFilter.addFilter(0, "MyType");
    autoFilter.refresh();

.........
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.